# Share data between users does not work in Android 10

Tags: android, multi-user, android-10.0

In my app I use obb directory https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getObbDir() for sharing files between users. It worked fine on pre-Android 10 devices. And it stopped working on Android 10. Now each user sees his own view of this directory and does not see changes made by other users.